# Using .htaccess to house two websites in one hosting space

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

As the question suggests: I have two domains/websites and I want to use one shared hosting area to house them both.

One website/domain will run from the root... and the other will run from a folder situated inside root.

I've managed to get the htaccess file to do this but I need the url to be disguised so that the site that uses the folder appears to be its own domain name (instead of showing the other domain name and folder its pointing to)

So the below...

Site1 -> site1.com
Site2 -> site1.com/site2/

should be...

Site1 -> site1.com
Site2 -> site2.com

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main\-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub\-folder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub-folder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main\-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub-folder/index.php [L]
```

It will just be a matter of using the rewrite engine so that the actual url doesn't show.

Comment: So are you indicating that main-domain is site1 or site2?